Can Digital Potentiometer outputs be paralleled?
Basically, a simple question. Do digital potentiometers behave exactly as resistances, assuming voltage and frequency parameters are adhered to?
In other words, if the input is floating is that also true of the output?
More info: The chip is MCP41050-I_SN. I am using PA0 and PW0 tied together as input (which may float) and PB0 as the output

resistive ladder + cmos switches, probably, staying within the I/O protection diodes to rails, though it won't hurt to quote some specific part numbers.

It's not a simple question. You are leaving out info such as which type of digipot and how you intend to use them and parallel the outputs. Which terminals you even consider the "input" and "output" depends on the circuit. When it is known what you intend to do, a suitable digipot with suitable configuration can be selected. Do you intend to use it as potentiometer mode (in which case the resistance does not matter much) or in rheostat mode (where even the wiper resistance needs to be accounted for)?

@Neil_UK Part number added
